# List of all quest rewards in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been searching around the web for a good list of all the main quest rewards in diablo 3, and have been unable to find one so far; everything has been objective lists or pay for guides or incomplete/outdated wiki entries. Does anyone know of a good list?

Comment: Isn't it all just XP/Gold scaled to your level?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Not scaled, it's set by the difficulty/quest, otherwise I could farm a normal quest and level quicker or at least the same speed as farming a hell quest.

Comment: @Mr Smooth scaling goes two ways - it can be scaled *down* in content which your level trivializes.

Comment: Is this your actual question or do you have a more specific one behind this (e.g. "How can I quickly earn gold from quests" or whatever)?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yeah, that slipped my mind, but I'm still pretty sure it's not scaled, although I'll have to test it.

Comment: I'm 90% sure it's not scaled in either direction. You get less gold/exp for repeating quests, so there's a disincentive to farm the same quests for progression without having things scale down as you gain levels as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not scaled, and in response to Nick, what I'm trying to get at here is a resource that helps analyze good spots for gold farming/power leveling as time goes on. So yeah, I suppose quickly earning gold from quests could be included in this question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, this is a perfectly valid and answerable question *(even if the rewards are not static, and even if we don't know what the equation for rewards is yet.  History tells me someone will reverse-engineer it in the near future)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive list of quests including rewards (gold and xp) [here](http://www.d3lexicon.com/act) (sorted by the acts). Hover the quest title to see the rewards per difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real 'rewards' from the quests, it's just gold and experience each time. The gold and experience scales down with level to a point dictated by whether the content is 'current' for you or not, and is replaced with a pure gold bonus once you are ineligible to get experience (ie: are level 60).

Comment: The obvious exception to this is the crown quest in Act 1; where you get the 'Town Portal' ability as a quest reward instead of gold.

Answer (score 0):

The official strategy guide has all the quest rewards listed, but from testing in-game I've found it does indeed scale with your level, both for being over and under the target level, so there's no hard numbers on how much you'll get.  Also I'm not sure if anyone has posted a list of all of them together or not, but your best bet would be to check a guide.

Comment: Where is there such a guide that you are talking about?